# Lost email settings and no icon for Mail

Tags: iphone, mobile-mail

I've lost my Settings → Mail, Contacts, and Calendars on my iPhone 5.  No icon for Mail and no Mail settings.  How do I get it back?

Answer (score 2):

On iOS 10 you can delete stock apps. If you accidentally deleted your Mail app, to get it back, you have to search it on the App Store and reinstall.

They are not actually deleted though, just hidden, so you won't be downloading anything.

Answer (score 0):

Go to App Store and search for Mail (Not Mail for IPhone).  Download the app.  If you have previously set this up, it should load everything as if nothing happened.